# Deploy Java App to GAE Standard using Cloud Build

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, devops, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to deploy a Java application to GAE Standard using CloudBuilder.

My cloudbuild.yaml is as follows :

`steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args: ["app", "deploy"]
timeout: "1600s"`

I have an app.yaml ( which I'm not sure I need ), but the deployment always seems to be unable to find `appengine-web.xml`

I have a fairly standard Maven file structure, and `appengine-web.xml` is at `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml`

I've had a whole load of errors, mostly to do with appengine-web.xml, the most recent being

`ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml is required for this runtime.`

Has anyone got this sort of build to work?

By the way, deploying using maven from my development machine works

`mvn -D skipTests clean package appengine:deploy`

**Edit with further information.**

I'm using Java 8

Target runtime is also Java 8

appengine-web.xml is as follows

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>myapp-staging</application>
    <version>alpha-001</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>

   <env-variables>
        <env-var name="ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME" value="myapp-staging.appspot.com" />
    </env-variables>

</appengine-web-app>
```

I can successfully deploy to GAE with the following comand when run from my development machine

`mvn -D skipTests clean package appengine:deploy`

Comment: 1)Which Java version are you using? 2)which is your target runtime? 3) can you share your  xml file? 4)does ```mvn -D clean package appengine:deploy``` works?

Comment: Do you build a fat jar or not ?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere : I think GAE standard expects a WAR file so I just use the maven-war-plugin and the google appengine-maven-plugin.

Comment: The question of @JoséSoní are relevant because your runtime version is impacting on java packaging and deployment. WAR for Java 8 but (fat)Jar for JAVA11 and the app description haven't the same form and don't be place at the same directory.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere: I edited my question with responses to Jose's questions. I'm not sure about the target runtime - I assume its Java8 but I'm not sure how to specify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Java 8 runtime, you have to use the maven command.

Try this step

```
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn"
    args: ["-D", "skipTests", "clean", "package", "appengine:deploy"]
```

Let me know if it works.

Else, you can switch to Java11 runtime if you don't use App Engine Java8 special flavor.

Comment: This works - thanks very much. It's quite slow as it has to download all the MVN dependencies and then install the Cloud SDK, but it deploys successfully.