# gcloud app deploy --no-promote fails in google cloud build without any logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

`gcloud app deploy --no-promote` fails in Google Cloud Build without any logs. My `cloudbuild.yaml` looks like

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
  args: ['package']
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ['app', 'deploy', '--no-promote']
timeout: "1600s"
```

The build step passes but the 2nd step fails immediately without any error message or logs. I am able to run the same command locally and it deploys but it fails in cloud build.

[image]

Comment: Is it work without the --no-promote? Can you provide the content of the app.yaml file?

Comment: Could you please try to use `gcloud builds log` command to check logs, and also check if `App Engine Admin` role is enabled on `xxx@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`. [More details] (https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/build-test-deploy-artifacts#deploying_artifacts)

Comment: The ```gcloud builds log``` game be detailed information. Initially it was admin api issue but now it sais ```ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) A custom runtime must have exactly one of [Dockerfile] and [cloudbuild.yaml] in the source directory; [/workspace] contains both```  Dockerfile is used for flex custom, I can't remove that

Comment: Maybe [Guillaume's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58219694/4786620) could help. You can use maven to deploy to GAE, and remove the second step. I think this step doesn't find the correct app.yaml file. It's probably the root cause.

Comment: I tried [Guillaume's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58205988/deploy-java-app-to-gae-standard-using-cloud-build/58219694#58219694) and it worked for me. I faced a permission issue while running the build but I was able to solve by giving "App Engine Deployer" role to the "<PROJECT_NUM>@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com" service account.

Comment: I tried that but it failed with  .No plugin found for prefix 'appengine' in the current project and in the plugin groups. I really want to keep the code generic and deoloy without making it defailt. BTW --no-promote has no effect.

Comment: https://github.com/neilghosh/spring-microservice-gcp-starter/blob/master/cloudbuild.yaml